# RTSP library in Python or C/C++?

Tags: c++, python, c, rtsp

I am trying to find any RTSP streaming library for Python or C/C++.

If not is there any other solutions for real time streaming?
How much easy or difficult it is to implement RTSP in Python or C/C++ and where to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [live555](http://www.live555.com). They have a lots of libraries and modules for implementing rtp and rtsp (as well as sip) into your c and c++ programs

Answer (score 2):

With Python and Twisted, you could use [this module](http://www.flumotion.net/doc/flumotion/reference/trunk/flumotion.twisted.rtsp-module.html).